# how to update a YII extension(yii2-fullcalendar)

Tags: php, yii, composer-php, yii2, yii-extensions

I have installed yii2-full calendar extension but it is not the latest version and installed the old version. Now I want to update it to the latest version2.3.0 using composer but not able to get success.
The new version is available as .zip but there is no way to update it via composer. Anyone has an on idea how to do this?

Comment: Can't you simply update the sources on the file system?

Comment: do you have an error message maybe? or you cannot find the way to update at all?

Comment: i have tried to update it from composer by using 'composer update' it didn't returned any error and completed successfully but still contains the old version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different extensions. The first one that you use in your yii-project is [yii2fullcalendar](https://github.com/philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar) extension. Due to it's changelog the latest version is 2.2.3. Those would be installed and updated via composer.

The other one is the pure JQuery extension - [JQuery FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/download/) which has current version 2.3.1. This extension wouldn't be updated via composer.

So you have 2 ways - wait for the yii extension update or use second JQuery extension.